# Unsupported operand type(s) for &:'NoneType' and 'Node'

Tags: python

I am trying to implement linked list using `Python`. Since, i am new to `python` , i was improving my command on this language by doing some codes that i can do in `C++`.

```
  /* Function to get the middle of the linked list*/
void printMiddle(struct Node *head)
{
    struct Node *slow_ptr = head;
    struct Node *fast_ptr = head;

    if (head!=NULL)
    {
        while (fast_ptr != NULL && fast_ptr->next != NULL)
        {
            fast_ptr = fast_ptr->next->next;
            slow_ptr = slow_ptr->next;
        }
        printf("The middle element is [%d]\n\n", slow_ptr->data);
    }
}
```

This is a function which calculates the middle of the linked list.I tried the same with `python` but it throws me an error

> TypeError:Unsupported operand type(s) for &:'NoneType' and 'Node'

```
 def middle_node(self):
        slow_ptr=self.head
        fast_ptr=self.head
        if self.head==None:
            return

        while (fast_ptr.next!=None & fast_ptr!=None):
            fast_ptr=(fast_ptr.next).next
            slow_ptr=slow_ptr.next
        print (slow_ptr.data)
```

What am i doing wrong here and what would be the solution?

Comment: Try not to fall into the trap of writing Python in the way you'd write another language. For instance - many C idioms are really very non-Pythonic or don't exist and there's loads of builtins that make a lot of actual code unnecessary to write from scratch. In this instance - check out `collections.deque`...

Comment: @JonClements i agreee.Thanks.

Comment: eg: `d = collections.deque([3, 1, 4, 6, 7, 1])` then `middle = d[len(d) // 2]` is what you'd do here and then the `__getitem__` (the `[]`) will traverse the links as needed to retrieve your item...

Comment: So you can do `d[-3]` to traverse from the tail or `d[2]` to traverse from the head etc... all done for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want a logical-and operation, you should write `and`, rather than using the bitwise-and operator `&`. They have different precidences, so your current code is being evaluated as if you'd written `fast_ptr.next != (None & fast_ptr) != None`. That doesn't work, since `None & fast_ptr` is not valid.

You're also checking the two parts of the condition in the opposite order than in your C++ code, which makes the short-circuiting of `and` not work to your benefit (you'll try checking `fast_ptr.next` even if `fast_ptr` is `None` itself). Try changing your condition to `fast_ptr != None and fast_ptr.next != None`.

Note that unlike in C++, you don't need parentheses around the condition for a `while` loop in Python. It's also conventional (though not required) that you test for `None` with the `is` (or `is not`) operator instead of `==` (or `!=`). So a more idiomatic version of your `while` line would be:

```
while fast_ptr is not None and fast_ptr.next is not None:
```

Comment: it throws another error : `nonetype object has no attribute next`

Comment: When comparing with `None` you're better off using something like `fast_ptr.next is not None and fast_ptr is not None`

Comment: @PRMoureu why does this makes any difference?  didn't get it

Comment: `while fast_ptr is not None and fast_ptr.next is not None:` this works but `while fast_ptr.next is not None and fast_ptr is not None:` this doesn't, why?

Comment: @BOTJR. Blckknght keeps answering before me, if you check `fast_ptr is not None ` before, the test will stops if `fast_ptr` is None, and it avoids to return a error with the next expression

Comment: `is` can compare references directly, `!=` has to look up the object's comparison methods. `None` is a singleton, so `is` is appropriate.

Comment: The comparison order is because if `fast_ptr is None` then `fast_ptr.next` *does not exist*. C++ has the exact same problem. Ordering the tests helps because `and` and `&&` both shortcut; if the first value is false, the second is never evaluated.